# Django Admin ManyToMany error

Tags: mysql, django, admin

I'm using the the built in django admin site to save instances of a model that has a ManyToMany field. If I save, not update, a model in the admin site without setting a value for the ManyToMany field it saves fine. I can also come back and set the ManyToMany field after saving the model and that works. However, if I try to save a new instance of my model, Exercise, that has the ManyToMany field, Exercise.muscles, set I get the following error:

> (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`vitality`.`projectvitality_exercise_muscles`, CONSTRAINT `exercise_id_refs_exercise_id_a5d4ddd6` FOREIGN KEY (`exercise_id`) REFERENCES `projectvitality_exercise` (`exercise_id`))')

My mysql tables are set to INNODB.

My models are as follows:

```
class Muscle(models.Model):
    def format(self):
            return "name:{0}:".format(self.name)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.name)

    muscle_id = UUIDField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, default="")
    medical = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, default="")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")

class Exercise(models.Model):
    def format(self):
            return "name:{0}".format(self.name)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.name)

    ISOLATION_TYPE = "isolation"
    COMPOUND_TYPE = "compound"
    FULL_BODY_TYPE = "full"

    EXERCISE_TYPES = (
            (ISOLATION_TYPE, "Isolation"),
            (COMPOUND_TYPE, "Compound"),
            (FULL_BODY_TYPE, "Full Body")
    )

    UPPER_BODY_GROUP = "upper"
    LOWER_BODY_GROUP = "lower"

    GROUP_CHOICES = (
            (UPPER_BODY_GROUP, "Upper Body"),
            (LOWER_BODY_GROUP, "Lower Body")
    )

    exercise_id = UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="", blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
    group = models.CharField(max_length=255,
            choices=GROUP_CHOICES,
            blank=False,
            default=UPPER_BODY_GROUP)
    exercise_type = models.CharField(max_length=255,
            choices=EXERCISE_TYPES,
            blank=False,
            default=ISOLATION_TYPE)
    muscles = models.ManyToManyField('Muscle', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
            verbose_name = "Exercise"
            verbose_name_plural = "Exercises"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of debugging I found the issue. In my code I use UUIDField, from django-extensions library, as a primary key. When saving a new instance of Exercise model it is able to generate, set and save the primary key. However, when saving a new instance of Exercise that has the ManyToMany field set, UUIDField isn't generated in time. This leads to the Django admin attempting to insert a null/empty primary key, the UUIDField in Exercise model, into the join table which triggers the Foreign Key constraint failure.